# A object's property value will be used to as an another object's property in Handlebars/EJS Template engine

Tags: node.js, handlebars.js, ejs

```
{{#each CoinList}}
  <h4>  {{Prices.{{this}}.USD}} <h4>
{{/each}}
```

Here two objects are passed that are `CoinList` and `Prices`. We have to find the value `{{ Prices.a_CoinlList_value.USD }}` . But how will be ? Anyone please help me.

Comment: First object will be an array .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this will help you.

```
prices = 
{ BTC: { USD: 7341.59, EUR: 6265.94 },
  ETH: { USD: 562.31, EUR: 480.53 },
  XRP: { USD: 0.6044, EUR: 0.5173 },
  BCH: { USD: 987.25, EUR: 844.63 },
  LTC: { USD: 117.26, EUR: 100.52 },
  EOS: { USD: 12.31, EUR: 10.52 },
  ADA: { USD: 0.1913, EUR: 0.1633 },
  XLM: { USD: 0.2737, EUR: 0.2334 },
  NEO: { USD: 52.19, EUR: 44.63 },
  XMR: { USD: 166.34, EUR: 141.91 },
  DASH: { USD: 316.13, EUR: 269.06 },
}



coinList = 
[ 'BTC',
  'ETH',
  'XRP',
  'BCH',
  'LTC',
  'EOS',
  'ADA',
  'XLM',
  'NEO',
  'MIOTA',
  'XMR',
  'DASH'
  ]
```

This is for **EJS template**s though

```
 <%var i;%>
  <% for (var key in coinlist) { %>
      <%i=coinlist[key]%>
      <h2><%=prices[i]['USD']%></h2>
    <% } %>
```

**Happy Node**

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this:

```
{{#each CoinList}}
  <h4>{{Prices.[this].USD}}<h4>
{{/each}}
```

or this:

```
{{#each CoinList}}
  <h4>{{Prices[this]USD}}<h4>
{{/each}}
```

or maybe this:

```
{{#each CoinList}}
  <h4>{{Prices[this].USD}}<h4>
{{/each}}
```

Comment: Yes, i have already tried with that. But, still i have no correct syntax to write that.